# Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call in read at download.cgi line 39, near "$cur;"

Tags: perl

Hi i am trying to compile the perl program but it is giving the error.

Here is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

require './filemin-lib.pl';
use lib './lib';

use File::Basename;
use List::Util qw( min max );
use Cwd 'abs_path';

&ReadParse();

get_paths();

my $file = $cwd.'/'.$in{'file'};
my $size = -s "$file";
my $begin=0;
my $end=$size;
(my $name, my $dir, my $ext) = fileparse($file, qr/\.[^.]*/);

open (FILE, "< $file") or die "can't open $file: $!";
binmode FILE;

print "Content-Type: application/x-vlc-plugin\n";
print "Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0";
print "Pragma: no-cache" ;
print "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$name$ext\"\n";
print "Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary";
print "Accept-Ranges: bytes";
print "Content-Length:  $end - $begin \n\n";
print "Connection: close"; 

#open (FILE, "< $file") or die "can't open $file: $!";
#binmode FILE;

my $cur=$begin;
seek(FILE,$begin,0);
while(!eof(FILE) && $cur < $end)
{
    read FILE, min(1024*16) , $end-$cur;
    $cur+=1024*16;
}
close FILE;
```

In the i am trying to play the video with the help of `vlc-plugin` and i am trying to play the video file.But i am not getting where i am going wrong.But for this i am getting error

`Can't modify non-lvalue subroutine call in read at download.cgi line 39, near "$cur;"`

Please someone help me out.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `use strict;` `use warnings;` at beginning of script is highly advisable.

Comment: docs of read: `read( FILEHANDLE, SCALAR, LENGTH ) "attempts to read LENGTH characters into variable SCALAR`. You should provide the arguments correctly: give a scalar to store into, then a length as argument. He cannot store into `min(1024*16)` ( which is not an lvalue )

Comment: Also I am sure what exactly what the for loop that is in is actually doing. Perhaps a comment on what you are trying to do overall would be helpful.

Comment: i am trying to play a video with the help of plugin..i am unable to open the file

Comment: Have you turned on strict and warnings? For example, I cannot see %in being declared. Thus, $in{file} is likely nothing useful.

Comment: Just as an aside, if I want a user of my site to watch a video, I would personally use html5 and the video tag and let the browser worry about what to do. Works fine for me. Of course, I still need to know where the file is.

Comment: there actually i am parsing the file name from someother function

Answer (score 6):

Line 39 must be this one:

```
read FILE, min(1024*16) , $end-$cur;
```

since that's the only time `$cur;` appears in the posted code.

If you look at the docs for `read`, you will find that the second parameter must be a scalar variable, which is used to store the read data.

`min(1024*16)` is not a scalar variable.

It is a function call.

And the function in question is, as the error message says, a "non-lvalue subroutine".  An "lvalue" is a value which can appear on the left-hand side of an expression, generally meaning that lvalues are writable.  The output of `min` is not.  Even if it were in general, it wouldn't be in this case because the input to `min` is a constant, and constants are *never* writable.  If they were, they wouldn't be called "constant".

I *think* what you probably want there instead is

```
read FILE, $buf, 1024*16, $end-$cur;
```

This will read 16kb from `FILE`, starting at an offset of `$end-$cur`, and store that data in `$buf`.  But you may have been trying to do something else there, so I could be wrong about this being what you want.

I also removed the `min` entirely, because there's no point in using it on a single value, unless you've defined your own `min` function which does something other than return the smallest of the values given to it as parameters.  (If you have, then I'd advise renaming your function to avoid confusing future maintenance programmers.)

Finally, general Perl boilerplate advice:

- `use strict; use warnings;`  *Always.*  (Unless you have a very specific reason not to, you understand why `strict`/`warnings` doesn't like what you're doing, and you can clearly explain why you think it's OK to do it anyhow.)
- Don't prefix sub calls with `&` (`&ReadParse();`).  It's a Perl 4ism which is no longer needed in Perl 5 and has side-effects that you probably don't know about and almost certainly don't require.
- Use the three-argument form of `open` and lexical filehandles instead of doing it the old way.  So `open (my $fh, '<', $file)` instead of `open (FILE, "< $file")`.  This is doubly-important when you're getting `$file` from user input, which means that they could pass you a malicious value.
- Speaking of which, *always* sanity-check user input before using it to do things like open files.  User input is not trustworthy and, especially on the web, you should expect to receive malicious input from people who are trying to break your program in creative ways which will then allow them to do unpleasant things with the server it's running on.
- Finally, there are a lot of really good, easy to use, web development frameworks out there, such as [Dancer](http://perldancer.org/) and [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/).  I would strongly advise looking at one of those rather than rolling your own file download script.  And if you're trying to do streaming video (as the mention of `vlc-plugin` hints), then that's even more complex than a simple file downloader.

Comment: Instead of turning off strict and warnings, you can turn off those that you know are in your way, then turn them back on, e.g. `no strict 'refs;`...`use strict 'refs'`. I never have to turn them off entirely and in my private scripts, I sometimes do pretty weird things.